# Can not add migration in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Added a new field to `RegisterViewModel`:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Name ")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Added in `AccountController`:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email,
                Name = model.Name
            };

    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    AddErrors(result);
}
```

Now I want create a migration file, using command

```
add-migration newFieldName
```

VS generates the file, but it is empty.

```
public partial class newFieldName : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

Update: `ApplicationUser` class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I _think_ it's because `RegisterViewModel` is only a view model, it's not a part of your db context and it doesn't get saved in the database. `ApplicationUser` is what gets saved in the database and it seems it already has a `Name` property.

Comment: @DanDumitru Sorry,I forgot to add this class in question. I updated question.

Comment: And ApplicationUser is a property in your DbContext (or class that derives from it?)

Comment: @Duston It's default EF class

Comment: So you are trying to extend IdentityUser? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532987/how-to-extend-identityuser-with-custom-property). You should create a baseline migration before you make any changes (`add-migration InitialBaseline -IgnoreChanges`, `update-database`). Then make your model changes and add another migration which would be just the differences.

Comment: @SteveGreene Your answer help me a lot. Please design it as an answer and I will mark it as correct.