# Newly Added Fields in AspNetUsers Table not showing up in identityUser as prop

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-identity-2

Please Help I am new to Asp.net Identity, this is asp.net core 2 web api , I am trying to register a user to my ASPNETUSER Table , and i successfully created new fields (FirstName,LastName,Address).

[image: Newly Added Fields]

the problem is whenever i try to map my input to the new fields , it does not even show the newly added fields as prop ... but it shows (i.e Id,AccessfailedCount,Concurrency Stamps....)

[image: This is my AccountController]

This is my Class Where ApplicationUser is defined
[image: Student Context Class]

I Then Tried Using ApplicationUser Instead Of IdentityUser This Time I see all the prop(both my ApplicationUser And Identity User)..but then On running it i get this error [image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are creating an IdentityUser instance instead of an instance of the ApplicationUser class that extends IdentityUser.

See this post: [How to extend IdentityUser with custom property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532987/how-to-extend-identityuser-with-custom-property?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)