# Invalid column name in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have an IdentityDbContext like this:

```
public class MyIdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int>
{
   public DbSet<App> Apps { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Avatar> Avatars { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }


   public MyIdentityContext(DbContextOptions<MyIdentityContext> options) : base(options)
   {
   }   // ctor
}   // Cls
```

If I add a property to App,  Team Device, etc I can add a migration and update the database just fine.

Example:

```
public class Team
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AppUser> Members { get; set; }

        public string ABD { get; set; } <--NEW PROPERTY
}    // Cls
```

However if I do the same in my AppUser class:

```
        public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>
        {
           public string FirstName { get; set; }
           public string LastName { get; set; }

           /// <summary>
           /// What app is this user connected to.
           /// </summary>
           public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

           /// <summary>
           /// Where does the employee work
           /// </summary>
           public string Company { get; set; }

           /// <summary>
           /// What section of the company does the employee work in.
           /// </summary>
           public string Department { get; set; }
     
           /// <summary>
           /// Maximum device this user can use - 0 means unlimited
           /// </summary>
           public int DeviceLimit { get; set; } = 0;

           /// <summary>
           /// This users avatar
           /// </summary>
           public Avatar Avatar { get; set; }

           /// <summary>
           /// Devices connected to this user
           /// </summary>
           public ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }

           /// <summary>
           /// Teams that this user is a member of
           /// </summary>
           public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }

           /// <summary>
           /// Apps that this user is subscribed to
           /// </summary>
           public ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }

           public string ABD { get; set; } <--NEW PROPERTY (causes error)

           public AppUser()
           { }
}    // Cls
```

I get the following error:

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider.
>
> Error: One or more errors occurred. (Invalid column name 'ABD'.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the AppUser class look like?

Comment: @TimothyG. Just added it. I was actually able to add migrations for the Properties you see there but can't do it now. Maybe something to do with the EF version I'm using now.

Comment: this question will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532987/how-to-extend-identityuser-with-custom-property/40579369

Comment: You added a migration for AppUser with the new property and made sure the column was created?

Comment: @MattU IU did that for all the other properties FirstName, LastName, etc. and it added the correct columns in the DB. That was maybe 6 months ago though.  Not sure what's different now.

Comment: Right, but did you create a migration to add this new property column?

Comment: @MattU I get the error when I'm creating the Migration for `public string ABD`

Comment: Ohhh sorry, so you can't even create the migration? What command(s) are you using to generate the migration?

Comment: @MattU I figured it out. Answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I figured out the problem.

I had a `SeedUsers` method in my `Startup.cs` and because `add-migration` runs the whole project first, it hits an exception because of the mismatch between the un-migrated db and my new code.

I just commented out the call to `SeedUsers` and it worked.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah, good catch, I didn't even think about that. I was wondering why something was trying to utilize a column you wanted to add via a migration, and that definitely makes sense.